# List in Sharepoint adding unwished extra rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

When I add a new item to my list in SharePoint, it keeps adding more rows with the same title by itself.

Can someone help me get rid of this problem?

Best Regards,

Melinda

[image]

Comment: Is there any Flow/Workflow or Event receiver added on the list??

Comment: I don't know, how can I see that?

Comment: I found it! It was a flow connected. I have removed it now so I will try to add a new item and see what happens

Comment: Great. check adding new list items.

Comment: Seems like it works, thank you very much! One more question, is it possible to change the date format to so it shows year, month, day? Instead of month, day, year

Comment: Welcome, please upvote and accept my answer given below.

Comment: In Order to change the date format, you need to use column formatting or create a calculated field. [Reference for Calculated column approach](https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/03/01/calculated-column-for-date-field/).

Comment: How do I format the column so it becomes year, month, day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a Flow/Workflow or Event receiver added on the list.

If there is any flow/workflow on a list then check which action/stage is causing this issue.

You can also turn off/stop it and then try adding new items in your list.